# Android Binding Abstract Class to Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I was wondering if there is a way to bind an Abstract Class to a Service?

I've got a Service that opens up a new Thread and communicates to a Node.js Socket.IO server.  I'd like to make an Abstract Class that contains the binding to the Service, Messengers and Handlers so that it can be used across multiple applications.  The intent is that I can create and Object of this Abstract Class and just need to Override onWhatever functions that get called based on whatever message the server sends back.

If I have to, I can just make a `public abstract void bindToService();` and Override it in whatever Activity is using this Class, but I'd prefer to make it a private method to the Abstract Class and have it called when the Object is initialized.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onBind()` method on the service, and return an implementation of the `IBinder` interface which can be the `Service` class itself. Then you can call `bindService()` from any `Activity` passing an implementation of the `ServiceConnection` listener interface, which will be called back with the `IBinder`. You can use that to interact with the `Service`. You can read more about how to implement `Service` binding this on the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Comment: I understand how an Activity binds to a Service, I was wanting to know if there is a way to bind an Abstract Class (Not an Activity) to a Service.  That way, the Activity has a private class that extends the abstract class, and when an Object has been initialized, it is bound.

Comment: @w3rthl3ss: `Service`s can only be bound to application components. If you want to implement the binding logic in another class, then you will need to pass it the reference to your `Activity` or `Application`. What you probably want is a `ServiceConnection` implementation, which will automatically receive callbacks when the `Service` is connected or disconnected, and will be able to interact with it via the `IBinder`.

Comment: I managed to solve this by using a `WeakReference` to the Activity in the class' Constructor.  Similar to your comment above.